# How to get value from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get value from js function and pass it to another function or make it global variable. I have variable a3 and I want to get the value from function `add()` but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Web Page</title>
        <script>
            console.log('hello world!');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form>
    a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
    
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
     <p id="greeting">Greetings</p>

  </form>
  <script src="java.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
 function add() {
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a').value;
    return a3;    
 }
var a5 = add();
console.log(a5);
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you getting as a result? Anything? Did you check to make sure that your JS is even running if you get no result?

Answer (score 2):

`return false;` is important in your case as otherwise after executing your `add()` function the default handlers for the button will also be executed which will actually reload your page. Here you can find a working example:

```js
function add() {
  var a3 = document.getElementById('a').value;
  console.log('a3='+a3);
  return a3;    
}
var a5 = add();
```

```html
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a" value="0"><br>
  <button onclick="add(); return false;">Add</button>
  <p id="greeting">Greetings</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `type="button"` to the button. This lets the form know that it is not a button to be used to submit.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write
`function add() { console.log(document.getElementById("a').value); }`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to the other answer. Your code is running when the script loads. So var a5 is being set not when `add()` is run, but immediately. Running `add()` from the onclick is getting the data and returning it, but returning it to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve but here a method that can create a global variable, and still pass that value to a function.

```js
// Cache all the elements up front
const a = document.querySelector('#a');
const greeting = document.querySelector('#greeting');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a listener to the button - no need for inline JS
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Global variable
let text = '';

function handleClick(e) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  // Update text
  text = `Greeting ${a.value}`;

  // Call the `add` function with
  // the input value
  add(text);
}

function add(text) {

  // Update the greeting
  greeting.textContent = text;
}
```

```html
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  <button>Add</button>
  <p id="greeting"></p>
</form>
```